# How to develop a vscode extension that is compatible with older version of vscode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I developed a vscode extension, using `yo code`. It works on version 1.75.0 and later. However, I was ask to make the extension compatible with 1.66.0.

I tried to modify the package.json

```
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.75.0" // I modify this to ^1.66.0
  },
```

However, I cannot build my extension after modifying package.json.
When I ran `vsce package`, it says

`@types/vscode ^1.75.0 greater than engines.vscode ^1.66.0. Consider upgrade engines.vscode or use an older @types/vscode version`

Then I tried to modify package.json again

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.75.0", // I modify this to ^1.66.0 as well
}
```

and ran `npm install`

It shows errors in node_modules and I cannot even debug my project.
`Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file:version, Position, Range...`. The conflict happened between `node_modules\@types\vscode\index.d.ts` and `node_modules\vscode\vscode.d.ts`

I removed the node_module folder and packae.json and ran npm install with

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/glob": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "16.x",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.66.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.45.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.45.0",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "glob": "^8.0.3",
    "mocha": "^10.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "vscode": "^1.1.34"
  },
```

It still shows the same errors. Is it because `"vscode": "^1.1.34"` conflicts with `"@types/vscode": "^1.66.0"`?

Comment: I don't use any `@types/vscode` in my extensions, but I only use Javascript, No TS

Comment: "_It shows errors in node_modules_" show us those errors. ([mre]).

Comment: @user It says `All declarations of 'xxxx' must have identical modifiers.`, and there are 100+ errors with the exact same format but different 'xxxx' in `node_modules\vscode\vscode.d.ts` and `node_modules\@types\vscode\index.d.ts`

Comment: Do a clean installation of all node modules. Remove the module folder and package-lock.json first.

Comment: You don't need `vscode` under `devDependencies`, https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/blob/190.1.4/package.json#L10 `engines` is all you need (and TypeScript requires `@types/vscode` as well).